# Flutter not able to build release version of application

Tags: flutter, dart

`flutter run` works but `flutter run --release` or `flutter run --release --profile` returns the error below:

```
===== CRASH =====
si_signo=Segmentation fault: 11(11), si_code=1, si_addr=0x0
version=2.18.6 (stable) (Tue Dec 13 21:15:14 2022 +0000) on "macos_simarm64"
pid=14192, thread=-1, isolate_group=isolate(0x7f910c011200), isolate=(nil)(0x0)
isolate_instructions=0, vm_instructions=0
Stack dump aborted because InitialRegisterCheck failed.
Dart snapshot generator failed with exit code -6
```

Here's my `pubspec.yaml` dependencies:

```
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.1 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.1.6
  table_calendar: ^3.0.8
  image_stack: ^2.1.1
  intl: ^0.17.0
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  flutter_riverpod: ^1.0.4
  auto_route: ^5.0.4
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  pinput: ^2.2.9
  mask_text_input_formatter: ^2.3.0
  firebase_core: ^1.21.1
  dio: ^4.0.6
  dio_cache_interceptor: ^3.2.7
  dio_cache_interceptor_hive_store: ^3.1.1
  http: ^0.13.5
  enum_to_string: ^2.0.1
  mobile_scanner: ^2.1.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.19
  image_picker: ^0.8.5+3
  image_cropper: ^3.0.1
  firebase_storage: ^10.2.18
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
  firebase_messaging: ^13.0.1
  hive: ^2.2.1
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  flutter_hooks: ^0.18.5+1
  hooks_riverpod: ^1.0.4
  local_auth: ^2.1.0
  lottie: ^2.1.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.7.0
  device_info_plus: ^4.0.1
  timeago: ^3.2.2
  url_launcher: ^6.1.5
  focused_menu: ^1.0.5
  rxdart: ^0.27.7
  rate_my_app: ^1.1.3
  infinite_scroll_pagination: ^3.2.0
  flutter_offline: ^2.1.0
  webview_flutter: ^4.0.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  web_socket_channel: ^2.2.0
  fl_chart: ^0.55.2

dev_dependencies:
  #flutter_gen_runner:
  auto_route_generator: ^5.0.2
  firebase_core_platform_interface: ^4.5.1
  build_runner: any
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.11.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter_icons:
    android: "launcher_icon"
    ios: true
    image_path: "assets/icons/b2b_logo.png"


flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  generate: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/
    - assets/animations/
    - assets/icons/
  fonts:
    - family: SnagIcons
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/SnagIcons.ttf</summary>
```

The application from 2 months ago was building successfully but as of last week, I have been getting this issue and reverting the changes i still get the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after raising the issue on the flutter channel, the problem was caused by returning a `late` variable from a future method so there was a fix in the release of flutter 3.7 which will remedy this problem
You can view the issue here [on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/117892)

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch to flutter dev channel and back to flutter stable.

Do a flutter clean and flutter pub get and try it again.

Comment: have tried this multiple times but it still fails

Answer (score 0):

This occours because of the some updates in the `packages`

Try entering the below code in the `vs code terminal`:

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub get`

Your flutter code will work like a charm!

#### Edit:

There are github issues which address this,see if any works for you

1. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43707
2. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/109818
3. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43597

Comment: i did try this too 
i even regenerated the whole project but the error comes back as soon as i tried to build or run in release mode

Comment: try using `flutter pub upgrade` and `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions` and see my edited post and let me know if it worked.

Comment: i have upgraded and normally and also with the --major-versions flag but still no improvements

Comment: One of the package update is causing you the problem. You'll have to figure out which one is causing trouble. Follow the above mentioned links that might help you